# Is there a word for the "call of the closing door" / "closing opportunity"?

Tags: word-choice

"Vertigo" partially refers to the nausea caused by observing a void, or large drop, with the overtone of the "calling of the void".
Is there a similar word for capturing the feeling of strong pull towards deciding to "go for it", in the context of a soon-to-be-expired opportunity?

Comment: What is *naunesia* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the expression   [seize the opportunity:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/seize+the+opportunity)   may convey the idea: (from TFD)

> - take advantage of an opportunity when offered.
>
>   - My uncle offered me a trip to Europe, so I seized the opportunity.
>   - Whenever you have a chance, you should seize the opportunity.

also the sayings:

> - leap at the opportunity (to do something) and leap at the chance (to do something);
> - jump at the chance (to do something); jump at the opportunity (to do something)

As for a term to define the sense of urgency to seize an opportunity : (from Wikipedia)

> - Fear of missing out or [FOMO](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_missing_out)  is a form of social anxiety, whereby one is compulsively concerned that one might miss an opportunity for social interaction, a novel experience, profitable investment or other satisfying event.

Comment: Yes, seize the opportunity is really close. However, I want to convey the *wish* / urge to do, as opposed to the action of making the leap itself

Comment: You mean a word for the sense of urgency that makes you seize the opportunity?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for

Comment: +1 for FOMO. There's also 'taking the plunge', or you could say someone is 'itching' to do something.

Comment: Yes, 'seize the opportunity is really close.' and 'However, I want to convey the wish / urge to do, as opposed to the action of making the leap itself' do not construe.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "(it's) [now or never](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/now+or+never)" can convey the sense that you must do something now because you will not get another opportunity to do it. Some examples from recent news headlines:

> "**It's now or never**": Britons scramble for residency in Spain and Portugal ahead of Brexit
>
> My health scare made me think differently, coaching Barcelona became **now or never**
>
> Production linked incentives: India's **now or never** manufacturing moment
>
> "**Now or never**": Heritage group rallies to protect 100-year-old fire station in Welland

Comment: This is closer, probably because of the sense of immediacy conveyed. But does it describe the _urge_ itself, or just the evaluation of the situation obtaining?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In some of the examples it's used to imply the motivation for a decision: Why are Britons scrambling for residency in Spain? Because they feel it's now or never.